# Change css header after scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, header

I need some help with my JQuery.

I would like to change the css of the header after scrolling, but can't get it work. The only thing that must change in the css is margin to 65px and delete the logo.

[Here is the code](http://jsfiddle.net/jssonline/dJh8w/)

```
#menuheader {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center top, center bottom, from(#fff),to(#ccc));
background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #ccc);
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #333;
height: 40px;
position: relative;
margin: 165px auto 0;
z-index: 10;}
```

Many thanks in advance.
Jason

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want to change the CSS after scrolling beyond a certain point, and then revert the CSS once you've scrolled back to a certain point, with jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    //After scrolling 100px from the top...
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 100 ) {
        $('#logo').css('display', 'none');
        $('#menuheader').css('margin', '65px auto 0');

    //Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
    } else {
        $('#logo, #menuheader').attr('style', '');

    }
});
```

Then all you need to do is swap out `100` with whatever point (how many pixels down from the top, while scrolling) you want the CSS to be swapped at.

http://jsfiddle.net/dJh8w/4/

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. It works exactly as i wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Plese clarify your question. Do you just need the jquery to change margin? or some sort of scroll handler?  Here is code for changing margin: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QUa4Z/) :

```
 $('#menuheader').attr("style", "margin:100px auto 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by a simple java script

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("header").style.padding = "1em 2em";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").style.padding = "2em 3em";
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure to add padding to the header in your css, unless it can't find the property

Comment: I prefer your solution because of using vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

Bind a function to `.scroll()` and have point to `$("#menuheader")` and do whatever you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website:

http://jsfiddle.net/fbSbT/1/

You can change the last function to:

```
$(document).on("scrollstop",function() {
   $('#menuheader').css("margin","65px");
   $('#menuheader').css("background","");
});
```

Comment: It works! thanks. Only 1 thing, when i scroll back the css does not go back to the original css. How can i fix that? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jssonline/dJh8w/) (I'm a beginnen in jQuery)

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the css back to its normal when the #menuheader becomes visible again?